# How to check whether directory is exist or not in batch file?

Tags: batch-file

I want to run command if the folder is exist, else i will execute another command

I tried below one

```
if exist "c:\program files\my File name\"
(   
   \\my commands...
)
else
(
   \\my commands...
)
```

but it doesn't work

> Note: folder name having spaces like "my file name"

Comment: The ELSE needs to be on the same line as both parentheses. ) else (  The opening parentheses also needs to be on the same line as the IF. This is clearly defined syntax n the help file for the IF command. RTM

Comment: @Squashman you mean it should be in single line?. because i have multiple command lines inside if parantheses, give me sample if you can

Comment: @mohamedfaisal, if you're checking for directory existence, you end it with a backslash: `If Exist "C:\Program Files\my folder name\" (`. However your question suggests you're checking existence of a file, so remove that trailing backslash: `If Exist "C:\Program Files\my file name including any extension" (`

Comment: What's the point of implementing the solution into your question? I rolled it back, because otherwise, the whole thread wouldn't make sense...

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the HELP file.

```
IF EXIST filename. (
    del filename.
) ELSE (
    echo filename. missing.
)
```

OR

```
IF EXIST filename. (del filename.) ELSE echo filename. missing
```

Comment: can you see my updated one. I tried the same way. it's just popping and disappeared. but not run the command

Comment: @mohamedfaisal, How am I supposed to know if the path is correct.  I don't have access to your computer to verify.

Comment: @mohamedfaisal, learn to debug your scripts.  You start by opening a command prompt and executing the batch script from the command prompt.  Do not run it with your mouse.  Also, if you have `@ECHO OFF` at the top of your script, change that to `@ECHO ON`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will help. Its unprofessional but it works for me.

```
@ECHO OFF
CLS
IF EXIST C:\batch\logs;C:\backup\logs (
echo THE DIRECTORY HAS BEEN MADE
) ELSE (
md C:\batch\logs md C:\backup\logs echo Directory created)
```